# Plot a list of tuples on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've data like the following

```
x = [(1,0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
y = [1, 4, 8.5, 17.5]
```

and I would like to plot in the following way

[image]

But matplotlib considers x as a 2 column vector so the `y` data is plotted twice.
Suggestions on how to generate a plot in the above-mentioned format will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also convert the tuples to strings and plot a categorical scatter:

```
plt.scatter([str(i) for i in x], y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps! may I know if it is possible to align the tuples vertically?

Comment: Do you mean rotating the xticks? If I understood correctly, you could achieve that by `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels` methods of an Axes object

```
x = [(1,0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
y = [1, 4, 8.5, 17.5]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(range(len(y)),y)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(y)))
ax.set_xticklabels([str(item) for item in x]);
```

The output figure is

[image: output]

Comment: `x = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0)]` and using same `y`. Now first and last point should be in vertical line but your solution doesn't produce correct results.

Comment: @Ch3steR thank you for pointing this out, I didn't see that, the other answer should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for what are you using but so try this way (create subarrays and add zero as second element.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn; seaborn.set()
x = [[1,0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]]
y = [[1,0], [4,0], [8.5,0], [17.5,0]]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

you willl get something like this

[image]