# How to connect the points of a scatterplot with a dashed line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I've a scatter plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [(1,0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
y = [1, 4, 8.5, 17.5]
plt.scatter([str(i) for i in x], y, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried to use the `linestyle` key to connect the points by a dashed line. Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

EDIT:
I'm using scatter plot for the reason mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980924/plot-a-list-of-tuples-on-x-axis/64981033#64981033)

Comment: `plt.scatter` does not draw a line between points. You can use `plt.plot` for this instead

Comment: You usually don't use `scatter` for that kind of plots. So, as already suggested, use `plot` instead, e.g. `plt.plot([str(i) for i in x], y, 's--')`

Comment: @HansHirse Could you please check my edit?

Comment: @tmdavison Could you please check my edit?

Comment: I can't see any reason for using `scatter` over `plot` from the linked Q&A. If I compare both outputs (`scatter` without dashed lines of course), they look equal.

Comment: @HansHirse Thank you! I understand the problem mentioned in the other post occurs when the x data isn't converted to a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [(1,0), (0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
y = [1, 4, 8.5, 17.5]
plt.plot([str(i) for i in x], y, linestyle='dashed', marker='s')
plt.show()
```